# Async link in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I got an url in my MVC application that goes to a controller like this

```
    public ActionResult Activate(int Id)
    {
        var Item = from a in db.users
                   where a.users.Equals(Id)
                   select a;

        users x = Item.FirstOrDefault();

        x.Aktiv = true;

        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Is it possible that when a user clicks the link in the view, that it goes to the controller and does this in the background and returns a result, kinda like ajax in jquery i guess?

Comment: "Kinda like ajax"? This is *exactly* what ajax is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controller methods can not be async, explanation is simple, how would the client know when the async method is ready? Like you suggested yourself, you should use ajax for async calls (in mvc Ajax.Actionlink).

There is a good article on Ajax.Actionlink: [see this site](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/ajax-actionlink-and-html-actionlink-in-mvc/)

Answer (score 1):

Add the MS Ajax libraries to your view:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

To call your controller action result you would use an Ajax call:

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Activate Me", "Activate", new AjaxOptions { Id = "1" })
```